# Why doesn't map[]interface{} take map[]SpecificInterface

Tags: go, interface, casting

The go spec states:

> A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface.

As such I can

```
type Source interface{}
type SourceImpl struct{}

var s Source
g := new(interface{})
s = new(SourceImpl)

*g = s
```

However, I cannot to the same with maps:

```
generic := make(map[string]*interface{})
specific := make(map[string]*Source)

generic = specific
```

gives:

```
cannot use specific (type map[string]*Source) as type map[string]*interface {} in assignment
```

Why is that? Can map of specific types be passed/assigned to map of generic types without using type assertion?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: Check the [assignability rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

Comment: The setup in the question does not match the types in the maps.  The setup shows that  a `*Source` can be assigned to an `interface{}`. To match the types in the maps, the setup should should show that a `*Source` can be assigned to a `*interface{}`.  This is not allowed.  In any case, see FAQ entry linked in first comment.

Comment: note that `interface{}` is already a pointer type

Comment: @ThunderCat true, thanks for the tip

Comment: I would really like to understand the down and close votes. The question is fairly answered by the golang FAQ but it is certainly not off-topic...

Answer (score 1):

Because `map[]interface{}` and `map[]SpecificInterface` are 2 different types.
If you make your generic type as an empty interface it can work.

```
var generic interface{}
specific := make(map[string]*Source)

generic = specific
```

But if you do so, you need to do some type switch or type assertion, when you want to work with your map.

Answer (score 1):

Because Go is a static type language , although interface{} and Source have the same underlying type , they can't be assigned to one another without a conversion.
Thus you have to do a conversion in a loop :

```
generic := make(map[string]interface{})
specific := make(map[string]*Source)

for k, v := range specific {
    generic[k] = v
}
```

Did you notice I changed *interface{} to interface{} ?
That's another problem of your code , in Go pointer to interface{} has not meaning.

Answer (score -1):

While not directly answering the question it seems that the go community is slowly starting changing its mind and started thinking about supporting generics for Go2: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md